# Understanding the linux scheduler

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, scheduling

I am new to linux kernel and low level programming. I wanted to know how linux scheduler is supposed to be O(1) in time complexity.

I came across the following article which is very informative but I have a problem understanding the pargraph I have reproduced below 
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-scheduler/

> The job of the scheduler is simple: choose the task on the highest
>   priority list to execute. To make this process more efficient, a
>   bitmap is used to define when tasks are on a given priority list.
>   Therefore, on most architectures, a find-first-bit-set instruction is
>   used to find the highest priority bit set in one of five 32-bit words
>   (for the 140 priorities). The time it takes to find a task to execute
>   depends not on the number of active tasks but instead on the number of
>   priorities. This makes the 2.6 scheduler an O(1) process because the
>   time to schedule is both fixed and deterministic regardless of the
>   number of active tasks.

Why 5 words of 32 bits for 140 queues ? Who the find-first-bit-set instruction helps to select one of the 140 queues ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A bit field uses a single value to represent a number of boolean states, for example if we were using an 8 bit integer then we might say that:

```
17 (decimal) = 00010001 (binary)
```

Which would indicates that the 4th and 8th boolean values are true, where all other boolean values are false.  In total 8 boolean states can be tracked as there are 8 bits.

As we wish to track 140 states (1 for each queue, true indicating that queue contains a task), 140 bits are required, and so as 140 / 32 = 4.375, we need at least 5 32 bit integers to store all boolean states.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
int bitmap_idx = priority/BITS_PER_WORD;
int bitmap_bit = priority%BITS_PER_WORD;

isSet = ( bitmap[bitmap_idx]&(1<<bitmap_bit) );  //test
bitmap[bitmap_idx] |= 1<<bitmap_bit;             //set
```

is used to reach the particular process with priority array and this is how bitmaps are used in scheduler which in turns depends upon struct prio_array

The article you pointed out is outdated check this one 
http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=101760&seqNum=2

Comment: Thank you. My question is very old and I had got my answer well.